# Best graph algorithm for least transfer in an electric grid

Tags: c++, graph, graph-algorithm

I'm given a series of cities, and each one produces an amount of electricity and needs an amount of electricity. Each city has up to 8 adjacent cities, and I am trying to minimize the number of transfers.
If A->B 10 energy, total cost of transfer is 10.
If A->B->C 10 energy (A to C through B), total cost of transfer is 20.
I thought about using Djikstra's on each point that needs energy, and ending the search for that point when enough energy has been found, but thought of several pitfalls.
I was wondering what else I could consider that could potentially work?
I also considered looking into the Floyd-Warshall algorithm as well as the Hagerup (read a bit about them on wikipedia and they seemed potentially viable)

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there's enough power? How do you evaluate a solution in which not every city gets the power it "needs"?

Comment: I'm guaranteed that there's enough power, and if I sum up the "lack in power" and the "surplus power" from all the cities, it will equal 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is easily reduced to a well-known [minimum-cost flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem):

> The minimum-cost flow problem (MCFP) is to find the cheapest possible
>   way of sending a certain amount of flow through a flow network.

This reduction can be done the following way. Add a dummy "source" and "sink" vertices to your graph, add directed edge from source to each original vertex with capacity equal to production rate at that vertex, add a directed edge from each original vertex to sink with capacity equal to consumption rate at that vertex. Set capacities and costs on your original edges as you need them, and solve the max-flow min-cost problem on the resulting network.

I also doubt that Dijkstra algorithm or any shortest-path algorithm will be of any use, as they are concerned with the path of only one unit of electricity from a particular city, and do not take into account "interference" effects from electricity produced in different cities. For example, if you have two cities (A and B) producing 1 unit of energy, one more city (C) close to both A and B consuming 1 unit of energy, and one more city (D) far away consuming 1 unit of energy, then you will have to route energy from either A either B to D, but no shortest-path algorithm will offer you this.

Comment: How would I choose dummy "source" and "sinks", given that there are multiple vertices that require energy/can give energy? Or does it not really matter

Comment: @AeonNeo, you should not "choose" them, you should _add_ them. These will be _new_ vertices with only purpose to convert a multiple-source problem to a single-source. For a similar idea, see, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem#Minimum_weight_bipartite_matching

Comment: @AeonNeo, or see here slides 3 and 4: http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~angelia/ge330fall09_maxflowl20.pdf

Comment: Hm, it seems like this should work but I still have a few questions/ I won't be able to tell until it's coded, but thanks!
1) It seems from the two links that the new Source/Sink nodes connect to certain points, is there any method with which I should choose these or do any work
2) I know that the max flow from single source to sink will be zero, and from my understanding the shifting potential energy from source to sink (the program doesn't yet know it'll become zero), will solve the imbalances. Is this right?

Comment: @AeonNeo, your first question is fully covered in my answer: "add directed edge from source to each original vertex with capacity equal to production rate at that vertex, add a directed edge from each original vertex to sink with capacity equal to consumption rate at that vertex". As for your second question, I don't understand why you think the max flow will be zero. The flow is not the sum of all production minus the sum of all consumption, the flow is the sum of all production, _or_ the sum of all consumption, which is equal.

Comment: Hello, I am currently planning out the process and was wondering what you meant as "capacity", as each node (vertex) can have an infinite amount of energy passed through it.

Comment: @AeonNeo, and each edge too? If each edge can have infinite amount of energy passed through, then you just set each edge capacity to infinity. Do not forget also that the edges from dummy source and to dummy sink still have fixed capacity equal to production or consumption in that vertex.

Comment: Yup, each edge can have an infinite amount passed through as well. 
I tried implementing this today using the max flow algorithm we learned in class - Ford-Fulkerson, which is greedy. The net "value" I gave each edge was equal to energyProduced - energyNeeded. I connected the dummy source to everything with positive net, and sink to everything w/ negative (gotten from the previously linked ppt). At this point, I gave the dummy sink a value of +infinity, so the "best path found" in 1 run would end on the first sink hit.

Comment: @AeonNeo, aren't you mistaking vertices and edges? Vertices do have produced and needed energy, while the edged do have capacity and flow through them.

Comment: At this point, I had it move energy from the first source (first node hit) to the last node (first and only negative value = sink), and start over. However, this seemed very similar to having 2 arrays - one of sources and another of sinks, then passing energy on. Essentially, I was stuck on working around 1) which sink to end at, 2) cycles. My current solution for cycles is to mark each visited node as "known".
In response to your latest response, I set each edge's capacity as the value of the receiving node.
A->B where B needs 100 would give the edge a capacity of 100.

Answer (score 0):

Ending the search as soon as you have enough energy isn't guaranteed to find the shortest path, but letting Dijkstra run completely for each point that's a power consumer will, and is probably still reasonable to do computationally depending on the size of the network.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup A* algorithm it improves on dijkstra with heuristics which might remove some pitfalls.
I can't really think of any other algorithm.

Actually I think A* should be fine.